# check if a library is present

Tags: c++, include, autotools

Suppose I want to include a library:

```
#include <library.h>
```

but I'm not sure it's installed in the system. The usual way is to use tool like autotools. Is there a simpler way in C++? For example in python you can handle it with exceptions.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Autotools would imply Linux, correct?

Comment: Exceptions are a run-time thing; `#include` is a (pre-)compile-time thing.  If the header file doesn't exist, the compiler will bomb out.  What do you intend on doing if that were to happen?

Comment: #include <library.h> is *not* including a library.  Perhaps this is merely semantics, but a ridiculously large percentage of the population does not understand that, so it would be wise to rephrase the question.

Comment: @trojanfoe Autotools does not imply Linux.  The point of the autotools is to provide a portable package that will work on a large variety of unix-ish systems, including Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

autotools is the best way to detect at *compile* time.  It's very platform-specific, but assuming you're on Linux or similar, [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) is how you check at *runtime*.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way of checking whether a library is installed using code. 
However, you could create a bash script that could look for the library in the usual places, like /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib. Also, you could check /etc/ld.so.conf for the folders and then look for the libraries.

Or something like that.

Comment: Those who do not understand the autotools are doomed to reinvent them.  Autoconf is a tool that builds a script exactly like you are describing.  It is much easier to learn autoconf than it is to re-discover all of the pain involved in writing such a script.